# IP.Board fill dropdown with data from mysql

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, ipb

So, I'm new do IP.Board and I want to access my database and fill a ***custom profile field*** dropdown list with data from my DB. For example:

table colors:

```
id  name
1   black
2   red
3   white
```

Now, this is what I want:
http://prntscr.com/58ytro
I mean, at least to produce the same results as if I had manually typed each line.

How can I do it / is it even possible?

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to acces database manually and use a `for` loop like inside the globalTemplate for your template as shown in "Look and Feel -> Manage Skins -> Manage Templates".